# Submit Button Event Tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: analytics

I can't get event tracking to work for a submit button press on a site.

The relevant code is

button class="btn-submit validate contact-btn " type="submit"  onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClutchEnquiry', 'Submit']);"    >SUBMIT

Is this syntax correct?

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits

```
    // Gets a reference to the form element, assuming
    // it contains the id attribute "signup-form".
    var form = document.getElementById('signup-form');

    // Adds a listener for the "submit" event.
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

      // Prevents the browser from submiting the form
      // and thus unloading the current page.
      event.preventDefault();

      // Sends the event to Google Analytics and
      // resubmits the form once the hit is done.
      ga('send', 'event', 'Signup Form', 'submit', {
        hitCallback: function() {
          form.submit();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: The drawback here is that if the visitor's browser blocks Google Analytics, but still has Javascript enabled, the original submission is prevented with `.preventDefault()`, but the callback is never hit, since the `ga` object is not initialized. This effectively prevents adblockers from submitting forms and provides no error message to indicate why nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct analytics object (ie. _gaq or ga)? It would depend on whether you are using Universal Analytics (analytics.js) or classic Google Analytics (ga.js) in your snippet. From you onclick handler, it looks like you may be using classic, but I've seen situations where the user mixes up the _gaq and the ga objects. Syntax-wise, it looks correct.

More information on the event push syntax can be found here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nyuen is correct. You most likely are using Universal analytics so the JS object you want to use is below:

New syntax:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'ClutchEnquiry')
```

Old Syntax:

```
_gaq.push['_trackEvent', 'ClutchEnquiry', 'Submit'])
```